# Including CSS and JS on Admin Screen of Custom Theme Options

Tags: theme-development, admin

I am creating a custom theme with a theme options page.

I would like to style the options page and do not want to include inline styles. Is there any way to include an external stylesheet from say

```
TEMPLATEPATH . '/css/admin.css'
```

I have also found this chunk of code and it seems to work - [link](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/)

```
function admin_register_head() {
 $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
 $url = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/yourstyle.css';
 echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$url' />\n";
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_register_head');
```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [create an admin theme plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) from the Codex steps, you will notice it says not to insert stylesheets as per above - although the above will work.

If you place the following inside your admin theme file, it will serve the same purpose, but uses the [wp_enqueue_styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Load_stylesheets_only_on_plugin_pages) approach:

```
function add_admin_theme_styles() {
    wp_register_style($handle = 'mytheme-theme-admin-styles', $src = plugins_url('wp-admin.css', __FILE__), $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('mytheme-theme-admin-styles');}
    add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_admin_theme_styles');
```

Answer (score 4):

When registering a page for the admin area, using `add_submenu_page` or any of the other `add_{TYPE}_page` functions the fourth parameter accepts a unique identifier, this identifier designates the hook your registered page will use..

If i were to register an options for example:

```
add_options_page( 'Example Plugin Options', 'Example Plugin', 'manage_options', 'example-plugin-identifier', 'example_plugin_options' );
```

Various hooks are then available for that page specifically, here are just a few possible actions for the now registered page.

```
// load-{HANDLE}
add_action( 'load-example-plugin-identifier', 'example_plugin_callback' );
// admin_head-{HANDLE}
add_action( 'admin_head-example-plugin-identifier', 'example_plugin_callback' );
// admin_print_scripts-{HANDLE}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-example-plugin-identifier', 'example_plugin_callback' );
// admin_print_styles-{HANDLE}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-example-plugin-identifier', 'example_plugin_callback' );

function example_plugin_callback() {

    // Run your code here

}
```

There is also the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook, which provides the name of the current handle in the string/variable it passes along to callback functions.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'example_plugin_callback' );

function example_plugin_callback( $handle ) {

    // If the handle is not the page registered earlier, return
    if( 'example-plugin-identifier' =! $handle )
        return;

    // Run your code here

}
```

You should not typically need to use `admin_head`,`admin_print_scripts` or `admin_print_styles` unless you have a specific requirement to target **every** administration page or perform conditional logic inside the callback to target specific registered pages.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Ah OK, this makes sense. Are you able to update the Codex page about creating an admin theme with this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes

Comment: I certainly could, but i'd have to sit down and build an admin theme before i go telling others how they should be doing it, time permitting i'll see if i can revise that codex entry..

Comment: Great! @abrudtkuhl, you should probably select this comment as the correct answer rather than mine I would think.

Answer (score 3):

WP provides queues for scripts and styles. It allows to version URLs, automatically load dependencies, etc.

See [`wp enqueue style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Load_stylesheets_only_on_plugin_pages) in Codex for how to properly register your style and load only where you need it (at your custom page and not all of admin area).

Answer (score 1):

Yea I am answering my own question ... but I did get it to work.

Add this action to your theme's functions.php file

```
function admin_register_head() {
    $url = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/css/admin.css';
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$url' />\n";
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_register_head');
```

Comment: If this solution works for you, you should click the "Accept" checkmark so others know you're no longer looking for it. But also check out the other answers, they offer good reasons why you should not write `<link>` tags yourself.